# Setting Image View as AlertLog Icon

Tags: android

In my Android App I have a Alert Log and an Image View. Now what I'm trying to do is to set the Image View or the Image Bitmap of the Image View as my Alert Log Icon. I try this Codes but its now working.

```
alert.setIcon(R.Id.Image);
```

Did anyone have thoughts regarding this problem?

Answer (score 0):

just replace the `R.Id.Image` to `R.drawable.Image`

```
 AlertDialog myQuittingDialogBox =new AlertDialog.Builder(this) 
        //set message, title, and icon
        .setTitle("Title") 
        .setMessage("Message?") 
        .setIcon(R.drawable.Image)

       ....
      .create();
        return myQuittingDialogBox;

    }
```

Comment: The Icon will be the same always. what I'm trying to do is whatever Image is in my Image View it will be the Icon of Alert Log.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this to know how to create alert dialogue with logo:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13506632/1627599)